# Empty file when resubmitting with same name c#

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I have 2 methods to upload files to Blob Storage. '`UploadFileToContainer`' is working fine, and i get files with data in container. The problem is '`UploadOrReplaceFileToContainer`', where it's not possible to use file.Position = 0, returning the follow error:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Specified method is not supported.'

Can someone help?

```
public void UploadFileToContainer(Stream file, string fileName, string userId)
    {
        string uniqueFileName = GetFileNameUniqueId(fileName);
        BlobClient blob = _container.GetBlobClient(fileName);
        blob.Upload(file);
        file.Position = 0;
        BlobClient blob2 = _containerbackup.GetBlobClient(uniqueFileName);
        blob2.Upload(file);
        _log.LogFileUpload(fileName, uniqueFileName, userId, DateTime.Now);
    }

    public int UploadOrReplaceFileToContainer(Stream file, string fileName, string userId)
    {
        string uniqueFileName = GetFileNameUniqueId(fileName);
        if (_container.GetBlobs().Any(b => b.Name == fileName))
        {
            _container.DeleteBlob(fileName);
        }
        BlobClient blob = _container.GetBlobClient(fileName);
        blob.Upload(file);
        file.Position = 0; //here is where i get the error
        BlobClient blob2 = _containerbackup.GetBlobClient(uniqueFileName);
        blob2.Upload(file);
        int fileUploadId = _log.LogFileUpload(fileName, uniqueFileName, userId, DateTime.Now);
        return fileUploadId;
    }
```

Comment: Check out [Stream.Seek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.seek?view=netframework-4.8), and it's companion property, [CanSeek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.canseek?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: What type of stream is it? Some streams do not support seeking.

Comment: @ferrub, ant update on this issue, could you use it with my way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error suppose your stream type `canseek` type is false. You could create a new `MemoryStream` and copy the stream to the `MemoryStream` then seek it or just set the position.

```
System.IO.MemoryStream blobstream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
inputblob.CopyTo(blobstream);            
blobstream.Position = 0;
//blobstream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
blob.Upload(blobstream);
```

Also you could refer to other discussion about this:[read a Stream and reset its position to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961308/how-to-read-a-stream-and-reset-its-position-to-zero-even-if-stream-canseek-fa).